# Show formulas + copy outside of Excel sometimes copies values, sometimes formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel after showing formulas, selecting some and copying in Notepad sometimes copies the formulas, sometimes the underlying values.
Anyone has any idea what decides which one is going to happen?

Using Office 365 if that matters.

If in a cell I have '=A1', and I want to copy this exact formula for other cells, the only way I know is to copy this is Notepad, and copy this as text to all the cells I want. 
I cant simply copy it with Ctrl+V, because it will change. Ctrl+X deletes the original. If there would be a way to Ctrl+X and make the original stay, that would be ideal.

Edit: I know making it absolute reference would work, but what if I have a whole range of cells with relative references? I cant go one by one and change them to absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Use Absolute reference on the formula by hitting the "F4" key. your example formula should look like "=$A$1" then copy and paste into new cells and they will all have the same reference.

Hope this helps, Please be kind and leave feedback!

Comment: Yes, this would work, but actually, I have a whole range of cells with relative cell references, and going one by one changing it with F4 would take too much time. If there would be a way to make them all absolute, that would work.